# Too Difference on Times for Querys to SQL Server from Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pymysql

I work with Python 3.5 and SQL Server 2014. I have got the next problem:

I connect to SQL Server through pymsql library.
When I execute querys on SQL which return more than 10K rows aprox the  spent time on python is much more that spent time on SQL Server.

For example, the next query spends 2 seconds on SQL Server and 9 seconds on Python. I think it is a very big difference.

```
 import pymssql
 import pandas as pd
 import datetime
 import time

 def connect():
# host y puerto a db
server = "GENIL2015\OPUS_1"
# usuario
user = "SA"
# password
password = "1"
# nombre de la base de datos
db = "OpusCentral"
# ejecutar coneccion
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, db)
return conn

def test_conected():
#conectar a db
conn = connect()

# HORA COMIENZO
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
df = pd.read_sql(" SELECT TOP 100000 * FROM DATA_NDX ", conn)
#print(df)
print(len(df))

#HORA FINALIZACION
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

    # cerrar conn
conn.close()
```

Some idea about why does it happend? Is normal this difference on times?

Thanks very much

Angel

Comment: Something seems to be pretty off here. My first question would be why do you want 100,000 rows in a single query? That is an awful lot of data to wrestle with in a single result set. And then I would point out that you got the top 100,000 rows but with no order by you don't even know what rows they are. I don't know anything about python but this has the feeling of an x,y question to me.